# Chrome won't display all HTML content

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

I have a simple HTML document well displayed using Firefox. However, using Chrome, it will only display a part of it. Viewing the source code with Chrome, I see this:

```
<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739104">A</span>TTGATGATATGTTGGAT<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739122">C</span>AAG<spa
```

`<spa` is broken, and what follows this is not displayed. My code in the HTML file is the following one:

```
<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739104">A</span>TTGATGATATGTTGGAT<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739122">C</span>AAG<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739126">T</span><span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739127">A</span>A<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739129">A</span>ATTTC<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739135">C</span>CTAATATTTGT<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739147">A</span>TGATT<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739153">T</span>AACTTATCCG<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739164">T</span>TGCTTTGA<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739173">A</span>
```

My `css` for `mnull`:

```
.mnull {
        background-color: #FFFFCC;
        color: #000000;
}
```

I do not show the whole code because it is too large. Do you have any idea about why it is happening with Google Chrome?

Comment: you provide too little information.

Comment: Can you post the `mnull` and `SL2.50ch04_49739104` CSS styles?

Comment: @Bas, just done it. `SL2.50chr04_49739104` does not have any css style, I use the `id` to identify it.

Comment: @KatrinRaimond, I provide the information that is available... Why negative votes?

Comment: @int11ap1 Alright, can you comment out the properties that stand in `.mnull`? Also, when you have opened your document in chrome, and open the source of it, do you see that span element?

Comment: With the code you've provided I'm unable to replicate this in the latest version of Chrome on Windows.

Comment: Same here. It's working for me. Try to create a JSFiddle to replicate the bug. (and what is the version of Chrome you are using ?)

Comment: In JSFiddle works, but in my `ChromeOS Google Chrome` doesn't.

Comment: Does it show the source code of the `span` element?

Comment: is it possible that you give us the link to your fiddle example, please?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: does it help when you add line breaks to your code?
So, when you write

```
<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739104">A</span>
TTGATGATATGTTGGAT
<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739122">C</span>
AAG
<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739126">T</span>
<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739127">A</span>
A
<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739129">A</span>
ATTTC
<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739135">C</span>
CTAATATTTGT<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739147">A</span>
TGATT
<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739153">T</span>
AACTTATCCG
<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739164">T</span>
TGCTTTGA
<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739173">A</span>
```

instead of

```
<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739104">A</span>TTGATGATATGTTGGAT<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739122">C</span>AAG<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739126">T</span><span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739127">A</span>A<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739129">A</span>ATTTC<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739135">C</span>CTAATATTTGT<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739147">A</span>TGATT<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739153">T</span>AACTTATCCG<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739164">T</span>TGCTTTGA<span onClick="reply_click(this.id)" class="mnull" id="SL2.50ch04_49739173">A</span>
```

?